# Do sencha supports Windows Phone?

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch, windows-phone-7

I am new to HTML5 Application Development.I am used to Windows Phone App Development.Is WindowsPhone supporting Sencha Touch Framework .And I have seen that Phonegap plugin in Visual Studio 2010 for Developing HTML5 Applications.But I cant find any plugin for Sencha in Visual Studio.And I am confusion which framework to choose  for development.Your suggestions are welcome.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Sencha does not currently support Windows Phone development. From http://www.sencha.com/products/touch:

"Sencha Touch is a cross-platform framework aimed at next generation, touch enabled, devices. 
It's currently compatible with Apple iOS 3+, Android 2.1+, and BlackBerry 6+ devices."

See also http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?177329-Windows-phone-amp-Sencha: 
"Windows Phone looks exciting, we aim to support it in a future release. Not sure on timing yet..."

Answer (score 4):

Sencha Touch 2.2 will now support IE10 on Windows 8 Phone and Desktop ...

- http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-with-windows-phone-8/