# Pragmatic solution for Sencha Touch 2 on Windows Phone 7.5+?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sencha-touch-2

Ok so [Sencha Touch 2 doesn't officially support Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484581/do-sencha-supports-windows-phone), although it may arrive someday.  But does anyone have a pragmatic solution to running a Sencha Touch 2 web app on Windows Phone 7.5+?  Such as a 3rd-party browser app that seems to work, PhoneGap / Cordova, other polyfills/libraries or combination?

Doesn't have to be perfect.  Most interested in functioning GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sencha Touch may announce support for Windows Phone in the future but unfortunately in the meantime the framework will not render in IE9 Mobile and therefore it is not yet possible to use Sencha in this context.

Comment: Thanks! I asked the author of the SurfCube browser, which is apparently built on IE9 and so doesn't help. Seems theoretically a JavaScript library/polyfill could support Webkit functionality in IE9 Mobile(?), but that would be a big undertaking that I've not seen evidence of yet.